# Convert PDF to word without using third party software?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, conversion

How to convert PDF to word without using third party software? I found several tools that claim they can convert PDF to word, but most of them are not free. Moreover those tools do not work well on the converting thing.

Comment: Have you looked at the free web based solutions, like https://smallpdf.com/, http://www.sejda.com/, or https://online2pdf.com/?

Comment: not yet. I'll have a look now. Thx

Comment: I realize it costs money to upgrade, not sure which version you have, but the latest version of Word does not need a separate conversion tool and will open a PDF file directly if needed.

Comment: Word 2013+ can do this by default

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified which version of MS Word you are using however if you have Word 2013 or newer it will automatically convert a PDF to Word if you open a pdf document with it.
Alternatively if you have an older version of Word you can open a free account at OneDrive, upload the pdf in your drive and then use the option to convert and download the file as word: http://newtechworld.net/convert-pdf-to-word-using-onedrive/

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do that from the pdf file itself.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. just tried your solution. it converts to text file successfully. but I have to pay money every month to convert word. anyway thanks a lot. the text format also helps.

Comment: But your answer didn't *really* answer the question. OP said in the question that some tools aren't free, which implies he'd like a free tool IMO.